# Cefsharp - keyboard not working until refocus

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am using cefsharp + cefsharp.winforms to create app that display webpage.
Application is being used on touch screen machines. On most of them it works beside one.

App is loading. We can touch screen to get focus in the input field, cursor is blinking but anything i write is lost.
One of solution is to press windows button twice then keyboard is active in application.

Anyone had same issue and managed to solve this?

Comment: What version are you using? How does Chrome behave on the  same computer? If Chrome works then I'd suggest opening chrome://version/ in Chrome to see if there are any command line args that are look related to touch screens.

Comment: it is cefsharp 73. other apps works. I can run notepad and write there. Then run my wrapper touch input and keyboard is dead until i press windows button or alt tab and return to app

Comment: @amaitland thx. I found your comments here : https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1811  This solved my problems. I test it on 3 different machines and only on one this was not working without those changes

Comment: This is likely a problem because you are using such an old and unsupported version. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2776 was fixed in version 81. The current supported version is 87.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i needed to implemented what is this comment:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1811
after that keyboard is working again

Comment: how to implement it in winform??? is not clear...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 In the link you have all you need. Just create your class that inherit ChromiumBrowser. Override IWindowInfo method with example from this link. Then in your app when you create instance of ChromiumBrowser create instead instance of your new class. Thats all